# "Local path doesn't exist " in Android studio 1.0.1 and Gradle error code: 255

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

i encountered this problem when i was trying to run application on mobile through Android Studio 1.0.1.
Infact, i have read lot of posts about this bug, most of them are about the older version of android studio . But i think this bug still persists in latest version. Help me to resolve it..

**DEBUG window logs:**

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: sony-c2004-YT910HWF5A
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\computer\AndroidStudioProjects\testapp\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.computer.testapp
Local path doesn't exist.
```

**Gradle Console Logs:**

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
 FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\computer\AndroidStudioProjects\testapp\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-e2f98987ccd5ddedc568c92f77e92365ed764b2e.jar C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\21.0.3\support-annotations-21.0.3.jar
Error Code:
    255
Output:
    'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 16.162 secs
```

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82388. Comment #33 in there has something which may help you.